# Issue with connecting VNC viewer to Wireless Access point on Wlan0 (static IP) - Pi 3 B+ Raspbien Stretch

Tags: raspbian, vnc, static-ip

So I installed VNC as so:

```
apt-get install x11vnc
x11vnc –storepasswd
cd /usr/local/bin

nano sharex11vnc
```

inside the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
x11vnc -ncache 10 -auth guess -repeat -nap -loop -forever -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -desktop "VNC ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}"|grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}"

chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/sharex11vnc
```

After reboot Im able to remote into my Pi no problem when its connected to my router and I use the provided IP from `ifconfig`.

[**Issues Starts Here**] Now I set up my wlan0 to have a static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.5.0
    broadcast 192.168.5.255
```

(^Source: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all#enable-packet-forwarding)

But when I reboot and try to VNC from my remote computer with `192.168.5.1:5900`, it won't establish the connection to the Pi. What step am I missing here?

Comment: what does "access point" have to do with your question? I don't see you setting up the pi as an access point, setting a static IP (the wrong way for stretch, by the way) doesn't make it an access point

Comment: okay so I would like to be able to access my pi remotely using vnc viewer, except I would like the IP on wlan0 to be static so that I can remotely view it anywhere without my pi needing internet connection. Isnt this possible? and could you please guide me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: so you do want the pi to be an access point - so, set it up as an access point (there are literally hundreds of results if you search)

Comment: yeah so im following this [guide](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/)  but im stuck on step 3 telling me to find `dhcpcd.conf`; when I `sudo nano etc/dhcpcd.conf`, it opens a new file, while the instructions say im supposed to scroll down the file which should already be there. Is it okay to just make a new `dhcpcd.conf` file with `interface wlan0  ---   static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24  ---   denyinterfaces eth0  ---  denyinterfaces wlan0` inside?

Comment: `etc/dhcpcd.conf` isn't always the same as `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` unless `pwd` is `/` ... but if you really do not have that file ... then you probably need to install `dhcpcd5`

Comment: yes you were right about installing dhcpcd5, thanks. I got through to the end where I have to start up services again but when I `sudo systemctl start hostapd` it doesn't work and returns "Failed to start hostapd.service: Unit hostapd.service is masked". Any ideas?

Comment: yep - I googled the phrase "Unit hostapd.service is masked" and found [an answer that explains how to unmask a service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017311/what-is-a-masked-service)

Comment: Thank you I still have further questions about adding a masquerade for outbound traffic on eth0. Im using `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` but it is returning `iptables v1.83 (nf_tables): No chain/target/match by that name.` I Couldnt find any exact source for a fix. I already tried to `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and then a `sudo reboot` but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's now the answer to this question? For the new question in the comment please make a new question.

Comment: okay I posted [this new question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/91635/94798) regarding my last comment. Thanks @Jaromanda X for the assistance previously

Answer (score 0):

So I am still following this [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) for creating the access point but Jaromanda X helped me solve my *initial issue* of assigning static IP to wlan0 in the dhcpcd.conf file.

**The solution** for not seeing `dhcpcd.conf`, was to install dhcpcd5

The *second issue* was trying to restart the hostapd service. The error was throwing "Failed to start hostapd.service: Unit hostapd.service is masked".
**The solution** was to unmask with `systemctl unmask hostapd.service`

My third issue has been posted [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/91635/94798) as a new question, as requested by user "Ingo" in the comments

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.